# How to use a select case statement if an array contains certain text (e.g. if rRng(i,k) contains "/2")

Tags: excel, vba

Edited at 17:29 09/04/2019 updated code to show variables part of my code that I left out of my original code

I have a range rRng that may contain:

1. Text
2. Numbers
3. Mix of Text and Numbers

I'm trying to use a select case based off what the cell contains (e.g. if it's a number, if it's a mix of text and numbers, or if it's a certain text)

The first row of rRng is the date (e.g. 8/1/2019, 8/2/2019, etc)

I've tried instr, contains, and like

```
Dim rRng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Set rRng = Sheet3.Range("HolidaySchedule")

For i = 1 To rRng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rRng.Columns.Count
        If rRng(i, j).Value = "Specific" Then
            'MsgBox rRng(i, j + 1)
            For k = iTargetCol To rRng.Columns.Count
                Select Case rRng(i, k)
                    Case IsNumeric(rRng(i, k).Value)
                        'MsgBox rRng(i, k) & " Working"
                    Case rRng(i, k) Like "*/2*"
                        MsgBox rRng(i, k)
                    Case "Vacation"
                        MsgBox rRng(1, k) & " On vacation"
                        Exit For
                End Select
            Next k
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

> **Expected:**
>
> - if it's a number, the message box should show the date and " Working"
> - If the cell contains "/2" in any part of the cell, the message should show the date and " Half Day"
> - If the cell contains "Vacation", the message should show the date and " On vacation"
>
> **Actual:**
>
> Only the "Vacation" message box shows despite the other cases being
>   true between k and rRng.Columns.Count

Comment: What is 'i'? Where do you set 'rRng'? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In this case, I think it would be better if you try your cases using `Ìf...Then...Elseif...Then....End if`

Comment: Because you did `Select Case rRng(i, k)`, you are expected to evaluate the value of that... and the only time you're doing that is in the `Case "Vacation"`. You should probably follow Fox's advice in this case.

Comment: Change it to: `Select Case True`, and the third condition to `rRng(i, k) = "Vacation"`, this is the way to make it work, but the `If..` structure suggested above should be way more readible.

Comment: JvdV - updated text to show declaration of variables
Foxfire And Burns And Burns - got it! I'm familiar with regular coding of if statements but wanted to try to use select case
FAB & BrakNicku - got it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like the following

```
Dim msg As String

'k starts as the column  of the specified date
'rRng includes each of the cases between k to rRng.Columns.Count
For k = iTargetCol To rRng.Columns.Count
    msg = rRng(1, k).Value2

    ' This is to see if a number
    If IsNumeric(rRng(i, k).Value2) Then
        msg = msg & " Working"
    ' This is to account if it's "Sick/2" or "Vacation/2" etc
    ElseIf rRng(i, k).Value2 Like "*/2" Then
        msg = msg & " Half-day"
    ElseIf rRng(i, k).Value2 = "Vacation" Then
        msg = msg & " On vacation"
    Else
        msg = vbNullString
    End If

    If Not msg = vbNullString Then MsgBox prompt:=msg
Next k
```

or using `Select Case`

```
Dim msg As String

'k starts as the column  of the specified date
'rRng includes each of the cases between k to rRng.Columns.Count
For k = iTargetCol To rRng.Columns.Count
    msg = rRng(1, k).Value2

    Select Case True
        ' This is to see if a number
        Case IsNumeric(rRng(i, k).Value2)
            msg = msg & " Working"
        ' This is to account if it's "Sick/2" or "Vacation/2" etc
        Case rRng(i, k).Value2 Like "*/2"
            msg = msg & " Half-day"
        Case rRng(i, k).Value2 = "Vacation"
            msg = msg & " On vacation"
        Case Else:
            msg = vbNullString
    End Select

    If Not msg = vbNullString Then MsgBox prompt:=msg
Next k
```

Although, do you really want 'n' number of message boxes?

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I originally had as the code but wanted to use select case (trying to learn some VBA language). Thank you!

To answer your question, I'm actually looking for 'n' number of message boxes, the message boxes are just for testing my code as of now.